# Prove that $T$ is invertible if $(T\circ T)+T −2I_V = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

I'm having difficulty proving the following:

> Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation such that $(T\circ T)+T −2I_V = 0$. Prove that $T$ is invertible.

I think that T might be equal to the identity transformation itself ($I$) but I'm not sure how to get to it from the datum.

Comment: I know the question I linked to is slightly different, but the same argument can be applied.

Comment: I see the similarity.. but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Using $T = I_v$ can I conclude that the invertible of $T$ is $1/2(T + I_v)$?

Comment: If you can rearrange that equation to something of the form $TX = I$, then $X$ will be the inverse of $T$.

Comment: Okay. thanks. Also I HAVE to show $XT = I$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(T\circ T)+T −2I_V = 0$

$(T\circ T)+T =2I_V$

$\frac{1}{2} ((T\circ T)+T )=I_V$

$\frac{1}{2} T \circ(T+I_V) =I_V$

$T \circ\frac{1}{2}(T+I_V) =I_V$

so $\frac{1}{2}(T+I_V) =T^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you. I managed to to just like that using @arnaud-d link.